# WP 3.0.5: Best way to add custom metaboxes for post categories?

Tags: categories, metabox

I haven't been working with WP for a while and noticed that there are some new features in WP 3+ such as creating meta data for taxonomies. I'd like to be able to add unique meta data setups for different categories on my posts - what would be the best approach for this? Take for example the following categories:

"press releases"
"cases"
"concepts"

In the first, I'd like the admin to be able to attach more than just 1 image (the default thumbnail). In the other two I need the option of an additional textbox.

Is this easier to do with custom post types? I'd rather work with the regular post categories.

Thanks,
-Staffan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress doen't have a term/texonomy meta table in its database so in order to save the meta data you will need to either create your own table hold the data, use the Options table to hold the data or use a plugin that creates that table for you like [Simple Term Meta](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-term-meta/).

some tutorials

- [add meta data to categories using
  the options table](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields)
- [add meta data to taxonomies using
  the options table](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-taxonomies-extra-fields)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, will look into it. Tried a plugin called "Category Meta" which supposedly does the same thing but it doesn't seem to be working with the latest release of WP (or it might be because my installation is in another language than English).

Comment: I can't really tell about that plugin as i haven't used it before.

Comment: I ended up using the "Verve Meta Boxes" plugin. While the meta can't be specified to a specific category it does apply to both pages and posts, and the plugin's very easy to manage.

Comment: But using Verve meta boxes misses the whole point of adding extra fields to categories or taxonomies.

Comment: Yes, but I needed to have this done fast. Had to find another solution.

Comment: I just don't get how using verve meta boxes helps you add fields to categories?

Answer (score 1):

You can try my plugin, [KC Settings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kc-settings/) which supports creating settings page for theme, plugins, post metadata (custom fields) and terms metadata. There are a few sample files inside the plugin directory and a short guide on how to use them. Feedback would be awesome :)